# Planning to start a right game design pattern

Tags: c++, qt

I'm planning start a game development (I did develop many promo games but now I will start my games with the best code design patterns). I will use QT Creator with C++14, OpenGL and some physical engines. Will I going on right direction? I will use it to compile in multiple plataforms (PC/MAC/iOS/Android)

Comment: There is nothing like the "best code design patterns". You just mold what you know of them to your specific needs. Start small then scale, if you hace never made a game before, it would be difficult to know how to organize the code without first making mistakes and rewrites

Comment: First rule of programming: [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle#In_software_development). Make it work, then make it better. Productivity is more important than perfection. Using good design practices is always a good idea but don't get too hung up on the details or you will never finish. Once you have hacked something together, then you reiterate and refactor, if you have time/money/sanity left.